# Skip test case if above test case failed pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Want to skip some test case below of a test case if test case failed.

```
class TestExample:
      def test_abc(self):
            print("Hello")
       def test_xyz(self):
             print("Hi")
       def test_aaa(self):
             print("World")
       def test_sample(self):
             print("Python")
```

Let's suppose test_abc failed , in that scenario want to skip test_xyz and test_aaa and go to test_sample directly

Comment: Then they are not independent tests, and should not be written as such?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that `test_abc` runs before `test_xyz` in the first place.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - so, the question seens _exaclty_ about how to write tests that are not independent - what you pointed out is not  a flaw in the question, is a clarification. It is not a common scenario, but I think it is valid.

Comment: It's also a hint to not write two (or more) test functions, but one test function that does all the dependent checks in sequence. Which is an _incredibly_ common scenario =)

Comment: in my scenario the condition is if one test case failed like lets suppose we get element not interactable then it should not run the other test case .but one last test case i want to run anyhow as that test case consist of summary result

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `pytest-dependency` plugin. Take the below code as an example

```
import random
import pytest


class TestExample:
    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_abc(self):
        print("Hello")
        assert random.randint(0, 1)

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TestExample::test_abc"])
    def test_xyz(self):
        print("Hi")
        assert random.randint(0, 1)

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TestExample::test_abc", "TestExample::test_xyz"])
    def test_aaa(self):
        print("World")

    def test_sample(self):
        print("Python")
```

In the example test_xyz will execute only if test_abc is successful, and test_aaa will execute only if both test_abc and test_xyz have passed. test_sample will be always executed as it doesn't depend on anything.

More information about the plugin can be found here:
https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html